# Clone / Bit copy a DD-WRT router

Tags: router, dd-wrt, dd

I have an ASUS RT-AC68U running a very specific and fairly complex configuration which includes a /jffs filesystem.  (The version of firmware is DD-WRT v3.0-r33525M kongac)

Is there a straight-forward way I can clone this system to another brand new router of the same model (which I can then tweek)  rather then recreate the config?    When I go to the "Backup" option it only talks about backing up the configuration file - which does not include the JFFS filesystem etc.

Comment: I know that if you have a working USB port DD can image from your router to the USB drive, but I can't find any examples at the moment.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas - the router does indeed have USB ports. I'm loathe to guess the DD solution for fear of bricking the device.

Comment: You won't, as long as you get the format of the DD command around the RIGHT way - Remember the order of input file (if=) and output file (of=)

Comment: Have you got an identical router? May be worth just using the standard backup on the source router and restoring on the destination router the same ddwrt build and then restoring the backup.

Comment: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=78906 - to give you an idea, but this won't be the same as your setup although ddwrt is based on openwrt

Comment: *"I have an ASUS RT-AC68U ... which includes a /jffs filesystem"* -- You probably mean a JFFS2 filesystem.  If this filesystem is in NAND flash, then *"cloning"* or *"bit copy"* would be a very bad idea (because of bad blocks in the source would not match up with bad blocks in the destination).